# dynamic accordion last element not deleted after updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a dynamic accordion like the one below , I have added an edit button to each result when on clicked deletes the data and recreates the accordion (ie repopulates function data from fresh data from the server) , it works fine till the last element in the accordion ,the last element even after being deleted is still persistent and remains in the list . though the data is null (no operation can be performed on it) . I am very confused on why this happens . So basically there is always one element left in the accordion

data is a JSon object with multiple objects in it .

{data[0]: name:{} , user:{}
data[1]: name:{} , user:{}      // the indexing is done to explain the structure
.
.}
etc

```
function data(data){
    var parent = document.getElementById('accordion');
    //parent.setAttribute('class','bookListItem')
    removeChildrenFromNode(parent);
    for(var i=0 ; i < data.length ; i++)
        {
        var listItem = document.createElement('h3');
        parent.appendChild(listItem);
        listItem.setAttribute('style','height:110px');


        var link = document.createElement('a');
        listItem.appendChild(link);
        link.setAttribute('href','#');
        link.innerHTML = data[i].first.name + " by " + data[i].last.name;

        var pic = document.createElement('img');
        pic.setAttribute('src',data[i].book.pictureURL);
        pic.setAttribute('style','float:left;height:97px;width:64px"');
        link.appendChild(pic);

        var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        parent.appendChild(innerDiv);
        var innerList = document.createElement('ul');
        innerDiv.appendChild(innerList);
        //setting attributes
 edit.innerHTML ="Edit"
         edit.onclick=(function(i){   
         return function(){delete(data[i]);  
         }})(i);
         innerDiv.appendChild(edit);

    }
    $('#accordion').accordion('destroy').accordion(
        {
            collapsible:true,
            active:false
        });

}
```

Comment: its probably not a good idea to have your function named `data` that takes a parameter named `data`...

Comment: `// the indexing is done to explain the structure ..` Could you post the actual format as well as the relevant HTML? If you want you could also try creating a fiddle on jsFiddle.net